# Creating excel VBA macro that generates unique random numbers

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a macro that will essentially return random numbers based on a users input, however, I want each output to be unique (which is why the `randbetween()` function won't work for this). Below is what I have so far, but I keep getting a reference error. I have stitched this code together from a few different examples I found online so optimizing in any way would also be appreciated.

**Code:**

```
Sub RandomSample()
Dim cell As Range
Dim rng As Range
Low = 1
High = Application.InputBox("Enter population total", Type:=1)
Sample = Application.InputBox("Enter the Sample Size", Type:=8)
Set rng = Application.Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(Sample, 0))
For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Selection) = (High - Low + 1) Then Exit For
    Do
        rndNumber = Int((High - Low + 1) * Rnd() + Low)
    Loop Until Selection.Cells.Find(rndNumber, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing
    cell.Value = rndNumber
Next
End Sub
```

error window:
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShvsT.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub RandomSample()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim Sample As Range  'declare Sample as Range
    Low = 1
    High = Application.InputBox("Enter population total", Type:=1)
    Set Sample = Application.InputBox("Enter the Sample Size", Type:=8)
    For Each cell In Sample   'use sample in loop
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sample) = (High - Low + 1) Then Exit For
        Do
            rndnumber = Int((High - Low + 1) * Rnd() + Low)
        Loop Until Sample.Cells.Find(rndnumber, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing
        cell.Value = rndnumber
    Next
End Sub
```

***EDIT :***

```
Sub RandomSample()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim High As Long, Sample As Long
    Low = 1
    High = Application.InputBox("Enter population total", Type:=1)
    Sample = Application.InputBox("Enter the Sample Size", Type:=1)
    Set rng = Application.Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(Sample, 0))
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = (High - Low + 1) Then Exit For
        Do
            rndNumber = Int((High - Low + 1) * Rnd() + Low)
        Loop Until rng.Cells.Find(rndNumber, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing
        cell.Value = rndNumber
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @Jeeped - Missed it, thanks for pointing it out, answer updated.

Comment: you may also want to see the other answer about the type:= error.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Seems like I went completely in wrong direction.

Comment: I was still getting the error with this code, kurtz suggestion of changing the Sample type worked for me.

Comment: @Melk - I've added another piece of code, you might check.

Comment: Thank @Mrig - this works perfectly, updated to show this as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a formula that does what you want:

```
=IF(ROW(1:1)<=$B$1,INDEX(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & $A$1)),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" &$A$1))/(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & $A$1)))=0),RANDBETWEEN(1,$A$1-COUNT($A$2:A2)))),"")
```

Where A1 is the population and B1 is the Sample size

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your `Sample` uses `Type:=8` which is a `Range` and then you're trying to use it as a "number" in an "Offset" function.
Change this line:

```
Sample = Application.InputBox("Enter the Sample Size", Type:=8)
```

To:

```
Sample = Application.InputBox("Enter the Sample Size", Type:=1)
```

Comment: This does not address the abstract use of `Selection` in the code.